# Retrieve last substring and before last substring in a path

Tags: java, file-io

I have a folder having sub-directories and files in it.
I'm able to rename the file in a recursive manner. My problem is to get the last `A.2` and `PE0120A` and write it in CSV.
If the path is static, then I will count the number of occurrences and will get the values, but I don't know how many sub-folders a folder may contain.

```
public static void dirTree(File dir) throws IOException 
{
    File[] subdirs=dir.listFiles();
    for(File subdir: subdirs) 
    {
        if (subdir.isDirectory()) 
        {
            dirTree(subdir);
        } 
        else 
        {
            doFile(subdir);
        }
    }
}
```

> C:/f1/f2/f3/manoj/Manoj_Eclipse/PE0120A/A.2/filename.txt

the dir is the root directory through which it has to start my program
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcGGb.png)

Comment: Added the Java tag; as a general hint: questions that have been spellchecked attrack more positive attention, so I made all the "I" in the text capital, as well as starts of sentences.

Comment: "get the last "A.2" and "PE0120A" and write it in csv"? Show us an example of what should go into the csv.

Comment: found the solution:                
"String splitpath = file.getAbsolutePath();
  String[] pathsplit = splitpath.split("\\\\");
  
  int l = pathsplit.length;
  String version = pathsplit[l-2];
  String foldname = pathsplit[l-3];
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:/Users/wcadmin/Desktop/test_output.csv");
writer.append(vesioin);
writer.append(foldername);
writer.append(splitpath);
"

@marcus muller, HannoBinder thanks for your reply.

Comment: Manoj, please post your comment as an answer -- self-answering is explicitly encouraged on SO!

Answer (score 1):

the below code will get the last and last but one folder name. thanks for support guys.

```
String splitpath = file.getAbsolutePath(); 
String[] pathsplit = splitpath.split("\\\\"); 
int l = pathsplit.length; 
String version = pathsplit[l-2]; 
String foldname = pathsplit[l-3]; 
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:/Users/username/Desktop/test_output.csv"); writer.append(vesioin); 
writer.append(foldername); 
writer.append(splitpath);
```